# how to get a data from a span and transfer it to an other span using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

This is my simple code but it doesn't work with me

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
        pageEncoding="windows-1256"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function getdata() {

                    var s =document.getElementById("src").value;

                    document.getElementById("trg").innerHTML=s;
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <span id="src"> source</span><p />
            <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="getdata()"> <p />
            <span id="trg">Empty</span>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I want to transfer the value of span (id="src") to the span (id="trg") when I click on the button (ok). Can someone help me please ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span elements dont have values, to get the content from span src, use:

```
var s = document.getElementById("src").innerHTML
```